# how to improve jboss response time

Tags: java, multithreading, time, jboss, response

Environment is JBoss 5.1.0,
RestEasy web service deployed and load test with about 10 transaction per seconds.

Need to improve the response time of Resteasy Web service,
Then change the working thread number to 100.

jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml

```
  <!-- connectionTimeout and keepAliveTimeout should be greater than the
       Heartbeat period between SIPServer and XS.
       (Here 60s for an Heartbeat less than 60s) -->
  <Connector protocol="${http.connector.class}"
           port="${xs.http.port}" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           allowTrace="false" enableLookups="false"
           SSLEnabled="false"
           connectionTimeout="60000" keepAliveTimeout="60000"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" maxThreads="100" compression="off" />
```

while admin-console shows the result is not good, the max processing time is still great than 1000ms.

Max threads: 100 
Current thread count: 4 
Current thread busy: 4 
Max processing time: 1061 ms 
Processing time: 55.7 s 
Request count: 657 
Error count: 1 
Bytes received: 0.08 MB 
Bytes sent: 0.86 MB

Question is how to improve the response time of JBoss Web Service.

Comment: Not sure if it's jboss that's the issue if you are getting 1000ms response times. how do you know it's jboss that's giving you long response times (vs maybe your service implementation layer?)

Comment: The wireshark and web service log file show that the HTTP package is sent in time at SOUPUI (a load test tool) and the web service log file proves that the delay does not comes from web service itself.

Comment: The package road : 1 SOUPUI - 2 network - 3 network - 4 OS - 5 Java - JBoss - 6 Web Service, the wireshark proves that delay is not from 1, 2, and 3, the web service log file proves that delay is not from 6.

Comment: The remain points are OS TCP stack, Java VM and JBoss.